# Is there a way to write types for destructuring array of objects in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I need to write typings for a structure like this one:

```
const [{ start }] = myObjectsArray;
```

However I cannot write it as just a string, or an object like this one:

```
const [{ start }]: { start: string } = myObjectsArray;
```

Because in TypeScript I get an error, saying that it is no an array type. When I try to type something like

```
const [{ start }]: [{ start: string }] = myObjectsArray;
```

I get an error, that the structure is missing the property '0'.

What is the way to correctly write types for a structure like this one?

Comment: To fix the second attempt you can: `const [{ start }]: ({ start: string })[] = ...`. Anyway it will be clearer to define an alias `type Foo = { start: string }` and use it `const [{ start }]: Foo[] = ...` or `const [{ start }]: Array<Foo> = ...`

Comment: Also if the array is already typed, you don't need to define type manually - typescript is smart enough to infer the type correctly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I'd found the answer while I was writing the question, so I'm posting it here.

The way that turns out to be working in such cases is the next one:

```
const [{ start }]: Array<{ start: string }> = myObjectsArray;
```